# Cross-Origin Request funciona no Postman, mas não no frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, cors, axios

Preciso acessar minha API para envio de emails, mas toda vez que tento faze-lo pelo frontend da minha aplicação recebo um erro do CORS dizendo `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mvtechsolutions.com:21007/contact. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

Mas quando utilizo o Postman o email chega sem problemas...

Estou usando alguns headers que supostamente fariam minha aplicação de frontend ser aceita, porém nada resolve...

Esta é a minha requisição de frontend:

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://mywebsiteaddr.com:port/contact'

export default class ContactUs extends Component {

    send = () => {

        const message = this.state.message
        const url = baseUrl
        console.log(message)
        axios.post(url, message)
            .then(this.reset())
            .then(alert('Mensagem enviada'))
    }
}
```

minha index.js (API)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const consign = require('consign')
const AllowCors = require('./config/cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const port = 21007
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(AllowCors)
app.use(cors())

consign()
//.then('./config/middlewares.js')
.then('./api')
.then('./config/routes.js')
.into(app)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(port)
})
```

Meus headers:

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next) =>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    res.header('Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
    next()
}
```

Em tese isso seria suficiente para receber os emails, porém até então não obtive sucesso... Se puderem ajudar ficarei muito agradecido!

Comment: você está usando duas vezes um `middleware` de cors, o que pode estar acontecendo é que um pode estar sobrepondo o outro, tenta tirar o `app.use(AllowCors)`

Comment: Ja retirei o AllowCors, e especifiquei meu dominio. O erro mudou, agora estou com problema de "conteúdo ativo mesclado", mas creio que se eu fosse tratar neste tópico fugiria do assunto principal. Então provavelmente abrirei um novo topico. Obrigado por responder!